# Can I download movies on Amazon Prime Video on one device and watch it on another device?

Tags: amazon, amazon-prime

I have some movies downloaded on the Amazon Prime Video app on my laptop. Can I watch these downloaded movies on my mobile phone without having to download them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. When you download movie/series on one device, it gets saved in the local storage of that device under the app(Not accessible outside the app). You would have to download it again on the device you want to watch.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help !!